# SQL Server, basic question about "Invalid column name"

Tags: sql-server

Here is my code:

```
select 
    h.hacker_id, h.name,
    count(c.challenge_id) as num 
from 
    Hackers as h
join 
    challenges as c on h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
where 
    num = max(num)
group by 
    h.hacker_id, h.name
order by 
    count(c.challenge_id) desc
```

I just want to filter out other result and leave the ones with max count, but I get an error in the `WHERE` clause:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Server WIN-ILO9GLLB9J0, Line 9
>   Invalid column name 'num'

Please help

Comment: You can't use aliases that you assign in the SELECT part of your query in the WHERE part of your query.

Comment: if I replace                                                                                                        
    where num = max(num)                                                                              
with                                                                                                              
    where h.name = 'Rose'                                                                                      it won't be error, what is the differnece between the original column name and the one I created?

Comment: If you are trying to compare each hackers challenge count to the max number of challenges then you can't do that in one query, however, you calculate the value using a subquery of max count.

Comment: The SQL execution engine does not 'know' about column aliases until after the WHERE clause is used to filter the result set. The non-intuitive part is that you can use a column alias in the ORDER BY clause. This is a pretty good article that explains why: https://www.periscopedata.com/blog/sql-query-order-of-operations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to filter on other result and leave the ones with max count,

I do suspect that you actually want `TOP (1) WITH TIES`:

```
select top (1) with ties
    h.hacker_id, 
    h.name,
    count(c.challenge_id) as num 
from Hackers as h
join challenges as c on h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
group by h.hacker_id, h.name
order by num desc
```

This will give you the record(s) that have the highest count. If there are top ties, they will all show up in the resultset.

Note: as you can see in this query, you may use a column alias in the `order by` clause (unlike the `where` clause).

Comment: wowowowowow, thanks a lot, never learned or even heared of with ties before, it works perfectly with my problem. learned a lot from you. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is the max(num) per hackerid, you don't need a filter, the group by will do it for you:

```
select h.hacker_id, h.name,count(c.challenge_id) as num 
from Hackers as h
join challenges as c on h.hacker_id = c.hacker_id
group by h.hacker_id, h.name
```

But it looks like you are just looking for top 1 as GMB has suggested.

Comment: thanks for you help, you right what I am looking for is all the hackerids with max(num)